# Defining a class with a method

Tags: php, class

If I define a class `LOG` like this:

```
class LOG {
    static public function LOG(){
        return;
    }
}
echo 1;
```

When I run it, it shows nothing. If I comment out the method like this:

```
class LOG {
    /*static public function LOG(){
        return;
    }*/
}
echo 1;
```

It will show "1" in browser. Why doesn't the first code snippet work?

Comment: need more OOP basic concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

When you turn error reporting on, you'll get this error:

> Fatal error: Constructor LOG::LOG() cannot be static

Removing the `static` keyword in front of the function will work:

```
class LOG{
    public function LOG(){
        return;
    }
}
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/250501)

---

In PHP, when you create a class like this:

```
class LOG{
    static public function LOG(){
        return;
    }
}
```

<sup>*(With the same named function as the class)*</sup>

It will run that function as the `__construct()` method.
It doesn't reach the echo because of the `return;` statement you have in there.

If you comment it out, it should work:

```
class LOG{
    static public function LOG(){
        // return;
        echo 'inside class';
    }
}
```

---

But I don't think that's the error, there has to be something else. Turn on error reporting and let us know if there are any errors.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Oh,thanks you,I forgot the `__construct`.I think it case sensitive.thanks.